# How to get Dropdowns selected text where there are multiple dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have multiple dropdowns like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" 
        runat="server" 
        DataTextField="Text" 
        DataValueField="ValID" 
        AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" 
    runat="server" 
    DataTextField="Text" 
    DataValueField="ValID" 
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">  
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Both the dropdowns has different set of values they are unique. I did the following on ddl_SelectedIndexChanged funtion

```
DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
string selectedId = ddl.ID;
string selectedText = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
```

When I select values on the first dropdown I get correct selectedId  and selectedText.

My Problem:
When I select the second dropdown the selectedId is of the second dropdown but selectedText is always the first dropdowns first value and it never changes. I need selectedText to be that of the Item which I select in the second dropdown.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: @MethodMan, yes it is. He is casting the sender back to a DDL

Answer (score 3):

When binding the data to the DropDownLists, you must place them inside an `IsPostBack` check.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddl1.DataSource = source;
        ddl1.DataBind();

        ddl2.DataSource = source;
        ddl2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

If you do not the `SelectedIndexChanged` will fire each time for the DropDownList because rebinding data will trigger that since the previous selecedindex is overwritten.